# Pandas cross merge while combining a number of columns (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working in python's pandas with 4 dataframes, each of which have a column of unique identifiers followed by multiple columns of shared attributes. I'd like to generate the cartesian product of the first column, but sum the remaining columns of shared attributes for each unique combination.

[image: Example Data]

I have a working version of that that separates the first column out into a separate frame, performs the cross merge, and then looks up the shared attributes for each of its unique elements but it is *horribly* slow. There has got to be a smarter way to do this. Anyone have any tips?

Comment: Please provide your dataframes as text.

Comment: ...and also provide and example of the expected output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: examples of dataframes and expected output were included in the embedded image. If that isn't enough I can create some text ones to help.